# How to input data in dataframe basing on multiple conditions

Tags: python, pandas

| ID | Create Date | Last Modify Date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 03/31/2021 8:56 | 03/31/2021 09:46 |
| 1 | 03/31/2021 5:56 | 03/31/2021 09:48 |
| 2 | 03/31/2021 0:23 | 03/31/2021 09:47 |
| 2 | 03/31/2021 6:56 | 03/31/2021 09:46 |
| 3 | 03/31/2021 7:32 | 03/31/2021 09:46 |
| 3 | 03/31/2021 8:45 | 03/31/2021 09:46 |

Hello,

For the above table I need to comment oldest **Create Date** for each **ID** as **"Minimal"**.

```
import pandas as pd

inputFolder = os.getcwd()
filename = filedialog.askopenfilename(title="Select file:", filetypes=(("xlsx files", ".xlsx"), ("all files", "*.*")), initialdir = inputFolder)
df = pd.read_excel(filename, index_col=None, header=0) 

df.loc[(df.groupby(['BB Global ID']).agg({'Create Date': min})), 'Comment'] = 'Minimal'

print(df)
```

I tried to do it with pandas df.loc function but I'm having below error.

```
KeyError: "None of [Index([('C', 'r', 'e', 'a', 't', 'e', ' ', 'D', 'a', 't', 'e')], dtype='object')] are in the [index]"
```

Below is final result what I want to achieve:

| ID | Create Date | Last Modify Date | Comment |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 03/31/2021 8:56 | 03/31/2021 09:46 |  |
| 1 | 03/31/2021 5:56 | 03/31/2021 09:48 | Minimal |
| 2 | 03/31/2021 0:23 | 03/31/2021 09:47 | Minimal |
| 2 | 03/31/2021 6:56 | 03/31/2021 09:46 |  |
| 3 | 03/31/2021 7:32 | 03/31/2021 09:46 | Minimal |
| 3 | 03/31/2021 8:45 | 03/31/2021 09:46 |  |

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`GroupBy.transform`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.transform.html) for repeat aggregate values, so possible compare by original column:

```
mask = df.groupby(['BB Global ID'])['Create Date'].transform(min).eq(df['Create Date'])
df.loc[mask, 'Comment'] = 'Minimal'
```

Or:

```
df['Comment'] = np.where(mask, 'Minimal', '')
```